# teamcity build не подтягивается агент

Tags: build, teamcity

Установил агента на локальную машину, выкачал репозиторий проекта, теперь хочу прописать в новой джобе уже на сервере TeamCity новые build steps, но своего агента теперь не вижу в блоке "Совместимых" под ним написано:
Unmet requirements:
MSBuildTools14.0_x86_Path exists
Кто сталкивался, какие пути решения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычно, TC сам выкачивает репозиторий. Ну а теперь надо посмотреть в проекте условия, по которым TC фильтрует агентов и понять, почему агент ваш отфильтровался и попал в несовместимые

Comment: выкачал то он сам, неправильно написал, а не подскажете, может на самом сервере его нужно настроить?

Comment: Все настраивается в проекте, смотрите, какие там стоят условия